# how do I update another form gridviewdata based on condition on main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I have two forms `MainForm.cs` and `PopupForm.cs`

in `MainForm.cs` on button click i will open another form and want to show one by one value which is coming by for loop into grid view row

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    //which executes cmd commands for ItemListBox and based on that Want to show current item on grid view which is on PopupForm.cs
    // show gridview item
    // grid view bind
    PopupForm obj = new PopupForm(listBox1.Items);
    obj.ShowDialog();
}
```

PopupForm.cs

```
ListBox.ObjectCollection _projectList;
public PopupForm(ListBox.ObjectCollection objectCollection)
{
    _nameList = objectCollection;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void PopupForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");

    foreach (string items in _nameList )
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(items);
    }

    this.myGridView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

But this binds all items in one shot. How can I show one by one item as for loop goes?

Comment: Provide a method in `PopupForm` which will add single item. Then display new form and call this method in the loop. Or rather simply move creating instance and displaying `PopupForm` outside (after) `foreach`.

Comment: problem is how can i pass values from MainForm to Popup Form one by one in for loop . check updated question

Comment: Is it a beginner question or what is the problem of passing values exactly? You are already passing values by using constructor, but in your scenario you want to save instance of the `PopupForm` (make `obj` a field) and call method of it which will simply add row to `myGridView`.

Comment: @Neo It seems the codes don't perform a useful job. Probably if you describe your requirement and task of each form, you will receive more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to show the items one by one in a loop, you probably need to pass the entire collection to the dialog form, and then use a timer to display each item:

```
ListBox.ObjectCollection nameList;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private int rowIndex = 0;
private Timer timer = new Timer();

public PopupForm(ListBox.ObjectCollection objectCollection) {
  this.InitializeComponent();
  dt.Columns.Add("List");
  myGridView.DataSource = dt;
  nameList = objectCollection;
  timer.Interval = 1000;
  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (rowIndex >= nameList.Count) {
    timer.Stop();
  } else {
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = nameList[rowIndex];
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    rowIndex++;
  }
}
```

You don't have to show your form in a loop, so just pass the collection and show the form:

```
PopupForm pop = new PopupForm(listBox1.Items);
pop.ShowDialog();
```